# DataGridView with dynamic columns to RDLC report

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, datatable, rdlc

I'm trying to print a report (`RDLC`) that contain the same data presents in a `dataGridView`.

This is the DGV:

[image]

The first 3 columns are static, the others one are dynamic. This DGV is loaded from a `DataTable`that I create from a series of `Query`.

What i would like to do is print this table using the same `DataTable`.

This is what I've already tried:

- I tried with `Matrix` table in RDLC using my query and it works ok but the query only returns rows with data, so for the first row it only print 36-12,20 and 38-12,50. The query is quite complex.
- I've tried to create a `DataTable` with the same columns of the DGV's one to use in the creation of the reports. I can create the report with this but nothing is printed because my column's name doesn't match with the one in the original table (They're dynamic so...)

I tought i could also create a dummy db table with all the data I need with fixed columns (let's say max 20) and than just use that to create my report, not really a fan of this approach.

Any clue?